# Vue.js Compile, Render and Component Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

We have a string which holds content and aliases for components, for example:

```
"Hello there, my name is ...
<my-component />
And today is a good day ...
<my-component />"
```

We then need to render that component out, as we are currently migrating from Nuxt.js 2 to Nuxt.js 3.

In Nuxt.js 2, we used to do the following with it working correctly:

```
renderContent() {
    return '...';
},
render(h) {
    return h(Vue.component('code-wrapper', {
      template: this.renderContent(),
      components: {...}
    }))
  }
```

This worked both fine when running `npm run dev` and `npm run generate`.

Since we have started migrating over to Nuxt.js 3, we have tried the following:

```
return h({
    template: '<div>'+this.renderContent()+'</div>',
    components: {...}
})
```

Now this works when using `npm run dev`, but when running `npm run generate` the page loads for around 2 seconds and then the content disappears.

We assumed initially it might be an issue with a component, but after running the above code with just the template saying 'hello world' and no components, it was still disappearing after a few seconds.

We have tried using `compile` with the same affect, but as well as the disappear issue we also get components not found:

```
return h({
    render: compile(this.renderContent())
})
```

We have tried using the 'innerHTML' way, for example:

```
return h('div', { innerHTML: this.renderContent() })
```

The above method does stop the page from disappearing after a few seconds, but again, we then have the same issue of trying to convert the components inside the string.

Any suggestions on the above?